# How to download WebPage component?

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, dom, webclient

I am trying to download some webpages and keep them offline for later use, but once I save them as html most of included components vanish!!

I even tried to open them in WebBrowser and download them as html but I got same result.

A possible solution is to download the html generated by DOM Explorer.

Any idea ?

Comment: Are those components image or video or any other element of such sort?

Comment: they are data, which might change everyday (such as Foreign Exchange figures, Stock Market Figures ..etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the following solutions for you:

- Use an open source tool like [HtTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)
- Use recurisve download of wget -r
- I think there was an firefox extension to download all dependencies called ScrapBook

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for this solution ...better to get something Dynamic, so I schedule the downloads and process them later

Comment: Should be possible with HtTrack and wget.